# Last 2 digits of modular exponentiation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is there any shortcut way to find the last two decimal digits of a modular exponentiation (base always is a single digit number) without doing square and multiply?

As an example in 
$$2^{100001} \pmod{10001}$$

the last two decimal digits are 48.

Comment: So, what, you're taking the modulus twice?  First mod 10001, then mod 100?

Comment: @Mike,Yes, I want the last two digits of the first modular operation so it requires another (mod 100) on the result of the first mod.